# MS Excel - Down fill a column cells if the corresponding cells are not empty in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet, excel-2016

I need to down fill column 'B' if the corresponding cells in column 'A' ARE NOT empty.

[Here's a screenshot of what I need done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AH8kK.png)

and here's the [link to the above screenshot spreadsheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I_Hp3yZei7DjYY95rRTqxEQ_NKd7IXSH/view?usp=sharing).

Appreciate your help.

Comment: firstly, your sample picture did not help in explaining what was your problem and what you want to achieve; secondly, if possible please let people know what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume your data in `A1:A10` as below :

```
A1: asd
A2: (blank)
A3: ddtgf
A4: yufjg
A5: (blank)
A6: gjfhgf
A7: (blank)
A8: fgn
A9: ghn
A10: awsfg
```

In `B1`, formula copied down :

```
=IF(A1="","","image"&TEXT(COUNTA(A$1:A1),"000000000")&".png")
```